# How can I input text-box to paste the youtube url ytdl - npm

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using ytdl from NPM, and I was wondering how can I make a box to paste a link from a youtube video to download it, Actually the code is already set up to download a specific video from youtube, But i want to be able to choose directly from my app: Here is my code

```js
    <script>

      //Youtube Downloader script

      function youtubeDL(){
        var fs = require('fs');
            var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
            //here is the actual link, How can I change it from my application?
                var video = youtubedl('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90AiXO1pAiA',
// Will be called when the download starts.
video.on('info', function(info) {
  console.log('Download started');
  console.log('filename: ' + info._filename);
  console.log('size: ' + info.size);
});
 
video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myvideo.mp4'));

      }    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOM in javascript look at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

html

```
<input type="text" id="ytLink">
```

javascript

```
var youtubeLink = document.getElementById("ytLink").value;

function youtubeDL(){

    var fs = require('fs');
    var youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
    //here is the actual link, How can I change it from my application?
    var video = youtubedl(youtubeLink,

    // Will be called when the download starts.
    video.on('info', function(info) {
    console.log('Download started');
    console.log('filename: ' + info._filename);
    console.log('size: ' + info.size);
});

video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myvideo.mp4'));
```